# How to properly chain Firestore queries using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

**Context**

I'm trying to create a document list view with a filter sidebar. The documents are stored in Firestore and I'm using Nuxt with Vuex to fetch and store the documents.

```
export const getters = {
  plants: (state) => state.plants
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_PLANTS(state, payload) {
    state.plants = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async fetchPlants({ commit }, queryArray) {
    const docsRef = collection(db, 'plants')
    let snapshot;

    if (queryArray) {
      const q = query(docsRef, where(...queryArray))
      snapshot = await getDocs(q)
    } else {
      snapshot = await getDocs(docsRef)
    }
    const results = []

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
    })

    commit('SET_PLANTS', results)
  }
}
```

Then, in my ListView component I fetch the data:

```
export default {
   async fetch({ store }) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch('plants/fetchPlants')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    plants() {
      return this.$store.getters['plants/plants']
    }
  }
}
```

And use a simple `v-for` loop to output the data:

```
<div v-for="plant in plants" :key="plant.id">
   <h3>{{ plant.name }}</h3>
   <p>{{ plant.description }}</p>
   <span v-for="(value, index) in plant.properties" :key="index">
      {{ value }}
   </span>
</div>
```

Notice the nested `v-for` loop that takes in the plant's properties. These consist of stuff like 'Needs little water', 'Needs little sun' etc.

**The question**

I would like to create a filter sidebar in the ListView component that allows the user to filter the plants based on their properties using a checkbox for each of them.

As you might have seen, I already have a `queryArray` parameter setup inside the `fetchPlants` action:

```
if (queryArray) {
  const q = query(docsRef, where(...queryArray))
  snapshot = await getDocs(q)
}
```

This parameter could look something like this: `['water', '==', 'Needs little water']`

However, this setup only allows for 1 filter to be applied. How do I properly chain multiple `where()` clauses together using checkboxes?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your document and also queryArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `queryArray` looks like this:

```
const queryArray = [
  ['water', '==', 'Needs little water'],
  ['light', '==', 'Needs little sunlight'],
]
```

Then you'll have to add a `where()` for each field as shown below:

```
const q = query(docsRef, ...queryArray.map((item) => where(item[0], item[1], item[2])))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not very familiar with the map function, but aren't `item.field`, `item.operator` and `item.value` going to be undefined here?

Comment: @Cartman right, correct it. Each filter is an array.

Comment: Perfect! The only thing I'm still wondering is how I'm gonna get the filter values from a checkbox. Would I just put it as a value like this? `<input type="checkbox" :value="['water', '==', 'Needs little water']" v-model="selectedFilters" />`. That doesn't look very pretty.

Comment: @Cartman are you filters always going to be equality? like `==`? Then you can just store field and value perhaps.

Comment: Not all of these, some will be `array_contains` as well. So putting the query array as input value is fine?

Comment: @Cartman `queryArray` as array of filters where each filter is of format `[field, operator, value]` seems fine for this use case imo. It'll be much more straight forward to query it using Firestore SDK. You just need to ensure that you push the filter whnever a checkbox is chcked. Or another approach would be array of objects where each object would be like: `{ field: 'water', operator: '==', value: 'needs some water' }` and use the code that was in my answer before edit.

Comment: I see. I'm going with the `[field, operator, value]` format for now. Works like a charm, thank you so much!